# Is it okay to have exposed Google API key

Tags: appsec, api

After running MobSF static analysis on an application, the scan detected google_api_key as a possible hardcoded secret. Should Google API keys be encrypted ? Or is it okay to have them exposed if you add necessary restrictions ? Same question for google crash reporting api key or firebase database url api key, is it okay to have any of them exposed and have them easily accessible through a simple static scan of the APK of the app ?

Comment: I googled your title question: https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037?hl=en#:~:text=If%20you're%20building%20a,unexpected%20charges%20on%20your%20account.

Comment: thanks for the answer ! I saw that on google but after talking to a supervisor in the company in which I am doing an internship he mentioned that it doesn't pose any threat for them. I really didn't understand why and I thought there was a specific use case in which it was fine to have them exposed.

Comment: Exposed to who? Two trusted application developers? Everyone who uses the application? Entire company? Anybody who clones your GitHub repository? The exposure defines the level of the threat.